# is it posible to make part of a div transparant with the margin of another div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a website with css, html and js.

I have created a circular **div** with a *margin* and i have a **div** that is partly inside the *margin* with `postition:absolute` and i want to make the part that is inside the *margin* to be *transparent*

i made a illustration so you can visualise it
[The image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJYrZ.jpg)

black is the visible part of the circle **div**

purple is the *margin* for the circle **div**

red is the **div** I want to be partly *transparent*

i have made most of the graphics in **CSS** but the *background* is a picture that i want to still be visible

here is the code

```js
let clicks = 1;

function addDay() {
    const links = document.querySelectorAll('.socialsLinks');
    
if (clicks === 1){
    for (const bil of links) {
        bil.style.opacity = "1";
        bil.style.transform = "translate(0%, -235%)"
    }
    clicks += 1;

} else if (clicks >= 2){
    for (const bil of links){
        bil.style.opacity = "0";
        bil.style.transform = "translate(-50%, -235%)"
    }
    clicks -= 1;
}

  }

  var element = document.getElementById('circle');
  var style = getComputedStyle(element)

  console.log(style);
```

```css
html{
    height: 100%;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'allerbold';
    src: url('aller_bd-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('aller_bd-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

body{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)) , url('356357.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#circle{
    z-index: 100;
    display: flex;
    height: 66vh;
    width: 66vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #E867A0;
    outline: solid white 6vh;
    font-family: 'allerbold', serif;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 13vh;
    user-select: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: transform 200ms;
    margin: 2vh;
}

input{
    display: flex;
    z-index: 999;
    opacity: 1;
    height: 78vh;
    width: 78vh;
    border-radius: 50%;
    user-select: none;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 49.6%;
    left: 49.8%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: transform 200ms;
}

input:checked + #circle{
    transform: translate(-31vw, -50%);
}

input:checked{
    transform: translate(-34vw, -50%);
}

.socialsLinks{
    background-color: #E867A0;
    z-index: 98;
    opacity: 0;
    height: 12vh;
    width: 33vw;
    margin: 2vh;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'allerbold', serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 8vh;
    color: white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: grid;
    justify-self: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -230%);
    user-select: none;
    transition: all 150ms;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="socialsLinks" onclick="addDay()" id="XD" />
  <div id="circle">SOCIALS!</div>
  <div class="socialsLinks" id="twitter">twitter</div>
  <div class="socialsLinks" id="idk">facebook</div>
  <div class="socialsLinks" id="kommmerSnart">google</div>
  <div class="socialsLinks" id="vetInte">instagram</div>
```

if you have another better way of doing this plz recommend it to me :)

thank you for any help!

i have tried *CSS Mask* even though i might just have field to understand how to use it. i have also tried to find ways of doing it in JS by getting the size of the *margin* and trying to set the opacity for the **divs** inside to 0

Comment: I don't understand your graphic - what you describe as 'margin' looks more like padding (as it's got the element's border-radius). Is there a reason is has to be margin?

Comment: Maybe setting z-index of the red div smaller than the zindex of the black/purple element does what you need? If it doesn't, you've to explain your issue better.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to overlap different div in a `position:absolute` context you can set different css property `z-index¡ on the elements, an element with higher z-index overlap elements with a lower value.

Since you are talking about transparencies perhaps the problem can be solved with an `rgba()` background color? it allow you to define an alpha channel for your background color that make it partially transparent, alternatives can be linear or circular gradients as background color that allow you custom gradients on filling your background.

More info abount the desired behavior can help to provide a better answer